# New SSD showing in device manager but not disk management

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I've recently bought a new ZBook from HP and paid them to install a secondary 1TB SSD for me which they've not done correctly.

The SSD shows up in the laptop's Device Manager;
[Windows Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJzu1.jpg)

But not in Disk Management; [Windows Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1I2O.png)

I'm not sure how this should be properly installed, I'd usually use Disk Manager but it isn't there. Storage Spaces are an option and it shows there but I just want the terabyte as a `DATA (D:)` drive.

HP have offered no assistance and I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Seems that Disk 0 is not formatted. You have to [format](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-format-new-hard-drive-windows-10) it and select NTFS as file system.

Comment: Disk 0 is the C drive. The highlighted disk in the device manager doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show in the BIOS?  Is the BIOS configuring with the proper protocol?  Maybe it needs a special driver provided by the manufacturer?  Perhaps if you Downloaded a third party Disk Manager you could see it proper and initialize to Windows liking.

Comment: Not in the BIOS, only shows in device manager and storage spaces. Not too sure how to properly install it given this should've been done by HP.

Comment: Well until it shows in the BIOS with the correct protocol, then you're at a stop.  Windows sees it in the Device Manager I suspect cause it knows that 'something' is there, but doesn't see it in the Disk Manager most likely cause its not being assigned correctly within the BIOS.

Comment: Word of warning to you...if you are not knowledgeable or familiar with the BIOS and the settings then perhaps you should seek out someone that is...be it a tech or a friend, 'cause changing the settings there  incorrectly and saving can really mess things up for you.

Comment: If you do go into it and look, cool be sure to NOT save settings on the way out if you changed any.  You could go into it and take a picture with your smartphone and upload it here as a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still waiting to hear back from them